# If-then formula

Tags: excel, function, formula, excel-2013, if-statement

In Excel 2013 I want to run a formula that does the following:

If cell A1 is equal to zero then B1 is multiplied by 10% and C1 is multiplied by 20%, and D1 multiplied by (1-0.2).

Comment: In which cell(s) you want to put your formula or formulas?

Comment: Are the original values of B1, C1 and D1 fixed numbers or formulae ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have your data in columns A to D, you can type in the following formulae into columns E-G, which will be calculated from B, C and D respectively

```
[in E1]  =if(A1=0, B1*1.1,[whatever you want to happen if A1 NOT 0, e.g. B1])
[in F1]  =if(A1=0, C1*1.2, C1)
[in G1]  =if(A1=0, D1*(1-0.2), D1)
```

Comment: thanks buddy! really helpful! one more question tho! can i set two formulas for one cell? e.g. multiply D1 by 10% if B1 is equal to zero and multiply it by 20% if B2 equals to zero and multiply it by 30% if B3 is equal to zero! thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah you could use a `nested if`, e.g.
`[in E1] =if(B1=0, D1*1.1, if(B2=0,D1*1.2,if(B3=0,D1*1.3,D1)))`
It just uses the syntax `[test criteria, action if true, action if false]`

Comment: AWESOME! thanks man! u saved me hours of work :-) cheers

Comment: here is another question, can i set three different conditions in one formula? 
1)If A1<0.05 then B1*1.3 and if A1<0.1 then B1*1.2 and if A1<0.15 then B1*1.1
2)If A2<0.2 then B1*1.3 and if A2<2.5 then B1*1.2 and if A2<0.3 then B1*1.1
3)If A3<0.35 then B1*1.3 and if A3<0.4 then B1*1.2 and if A3<0.45 then B1*1.1
thank you once more

Comment: @user2202993 just keep nesting those `If`s